# Remove or empty all data from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (df) which I would like to recycle.  It's full of data and I would like to remove everything from this dataframe.  Would df.drop() work?

Comment: Can't you just call `del df` or just reassign?

Comment: If you want an empty dataframe: `df = pd.Dataframe([], df.index, df.columns)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to free some space

```
import gc

del adios_df
gc.collect()
```